# How to parse json responses when the thing to parsing has a "-"

Tags: node.js, axios

I am trying to parse the following response:

```
{
  'content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
  'content-security-policy': "object-src 'none'; script-src 'nonce-ZlYPVW+fabQcieONPWEgtQ==' 'unsafe-inline' 'strict-dynamic' https: http:; base-uri 'none'; report-uri https://csp.withgoogle.com/csp/elms",
  date: 'Sun, 15 Nov 2020 20:34:57 GMT',
  server: 'LMS Frontend HTTP Server',
  'cache-control': 'private',
  'x-xss-protection': '0',
  'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
  'set-cookie': [
    'session=eyJjc3JmX3Rva2VuIjoiOTVmYWRiMzM2YTg5NjhmZWYxNzYzMGM5NTJmNGIxOTI5Njc0MTMxNSJ9.X7GQ8Q.bFVDQmNuAksbDsJJV9oSFPcsH5k; Secure; HttpOnly; Path=/'
  ],
  'accept-ranges': 'none',
  vary: 'Cookie,Accept-Encoding',
  expires: 'Sun, 15 Nov 2020 20:34:57 GMT',
  connection: 'close',
  'transfer-encoding': 'chunked'
}
```

however when I do response.data.set-cookie[0].session

I just get "cookie is not defined"

Comment: Basically I want to parse something with "-" without node saying "blank is not defined".

Comment: Does `.data['set-cookie'][0].session` work?

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem is not parse to `json` because this works fine:

```js
//Object only with set-cookie to read easier
var response = {
  'set-cookie': [ 'session=eyJjc3JmX3Rva2VuIjoiOTVmYWRiMzM2YTg5NjhmZWYxNzYzMGM5NTJmNGIxOTI5Njc0MTMxNSJ9.X7GQ8Q.bFVDQmNuAksbDsJJV9oSFPcsH5k; Secure; HttpOnly; Path=/'
  ],
}
//Output json
console.log(JSON.stringify(response))
```

So the problem is reading the variable into the code. You can't type `response.data.set-cookie[0].session`. But Javascript objects properties are accesible as it were arrays, should using `variable['property']` should work.

```js
//Object only with set-cookie to read easier
var response = {
  'set-cookie': [ 'session=eyJjc3JmX3Rva2VuIjoiOTVmYWRiMzM2YTg5NjhmZWYxNzYzMGM5NTJmNGIxOTI5Njc0MTMxNSJ9.X7GQ8Q.bFVDQmNuAksbDsJJV9oSFPcsH5k; Secure; HttpOnly; Path=/'
  ],
}
//Output the first value into property set-cookie
console.log(response['set-cookie'][0])
```

Note that `set-cookie` property is an array, so to read `session` value you have to read the first array position.